# Only downloading new folders/files with rsync

Tags: unix, rsync

I periodically run a rsync command which downloads new files from my remote server.

The files that are downloaded are stored in folders, once I have downloaded them to my local machine I may delete folders (and their contents) that are no longer required.

When I run my rsync command again it will download any new folders as well as the old folders that I have deleted from my local machine which I don't want.

What I would like to do on rsync command is store the folder names in a file (like downloaded.log) and then use this as my exclude file for the next time I run rsync so it will not download these folders again.
I think it would be more efficient to store only the folder names rather than folders and filenames as by skipping the folder you would skip the file anyway.

Could someone explain how I could have the rsync command output the folders names?

Current RSYNC command:

```
rsync -avz --dry-run remote-host:downloads/ ~/Downloads/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `--exclude-from=FILE` and put the directories you don't want in this file.

For example if you have a dir test with folders a,b and c inside and you want to sync it to a folder test2 but want to ignore folder b and c, you need to create a file like following :

```
$ cat ignore
/b
/c
```

and then run the command
`rsync -avz --exclude-from=ignore test/ test2/`

**edit:**
To fit to your command
`rsync -avz --dry-run --exclude-from=/path/to/ignore-file remote-host:downloads/ ~/Downloads/`

and in the file /path/to/ignore-file make a list of contents that are on remote-host in the downloads folders like this.

```
subfolder1/
subfolder2/
```

**edit2:**
To make it automatic you can create a script like that

```
/home/youruser/scripts/add-to-ignore.sh 
#/bin/bash

for filepath in ~/Downloads/*
do
    filename=$(basename $filepath)
    echo "$filename/" >> /home/youruser/.ignorelist
done
```

And then run it like that
`rsync -avz --dry-run --exclude-from=/path/to/ignore-file remote-host:downloads/ ~/Downloads/ && bash /home/youruser/scripts/add-to-ignore.sh`

That should do the trick, and the list will keep the old dirs.

You could also use --log-file and --log-file-format to log what you've just copied in a file and then have a script to remove the beginning of lines, so you could use this file as a source for --exclude-from.

Comment: This is the idea, but the log needs to be dynamic so whatevers been downloaded should be added to the exclude file automatically.

Comment: Edited my answer, but I don't think you can make it automatic in rsync.